# Combine StackNavigator and TabNavigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

First of all, In my tab navigator I have 3 screens :

- StartRun
- Activity

I want to add Stack Navigator from the StartRun screen :

- Running

When Im in "StartRun", I click on a button "press and go to running page" to the Running Screen. But in the RunningScreen I still can see the the tab navigator

how to combine stacknavigator and tabnavigator together?

Here is my code :

```
const RunStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  StartRun: {
    screen: StartRun,
  },
  Running: {
    screen: Running,
  },
});



const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  StartRun: {
    screen: RunStackNavigator,
  },

  Activity: {
    screen: Activity,
  },
});
```

I want something like that :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question and what you're trying to achieve. What do you mean by combining `StackNavigator` and `TabNavigator`? if you want to combine them, then just put the screen in one navigator.

Comment: I updated my question, i hope to be clearer